# Make yum not installing dependancies if main package failed

Tags: yum, rpm, specfile

I have 3 packages `corepkg`, `corepkg-optB` and `corepkg-optC`. `corepkg-optC` depends on `corepkg-optB`, `corepkg-optB` depends on `corepkg`.
I've created a repo of these 3 packages. When I run yum install `corepkg-optC`, and `corepkg` failed, yum installs `corepkg-optB` and `corepkg-optC`. It is not what I would like.

I would like `corepkg-optB` failing if `corepkg` is failed and `corepkg-optC` failing if `corepkg-optB` failed because `corepkg` failed.

My specfile looks like this:

```
Name: corepkg
Version: 1.0.0

%pretrans
if ! grep -q foo /etc/hosts
then
    exit 1
fi

%package optB
Requires: corepkg = 1.0.0

%package optC
Requires: codepkg-optB = 1.0.0
```

I tried Requires then Requires(pre), but give me the same result:

```
# yum install corepkg-optC
error: %pretrans(corepkg-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PRETRANS scriptlet in rpm package corepkg-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch
  Installing : corepkg-optB-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                     1/3
error: corepkg-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch: install skipped
  Installing : corepkg-optC-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                     2/3
  Verifying  : corepkg-optC-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                     1/3
  Verifying  : corepkg-optB-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                     2/3
  Verifying  : corepkg-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                          3/3

Installed:
  corepkg-optC.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el7.noarch

Dependency Installed:
  corepkg-optB.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el7.noarch

Failed:
  corepkg.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el7.noarch
```

I tried Requires(pretrans) but it was a non-sense as everything is a single yum transaction.

All corepkg are mine, I can modify specfiles. Any idea? Thank you!

EDIT: package B and C are not dep but more like additionnal stuff to corepkg. It is similar to packages php-* or python-*.
Similar because my packages corepkg-optB and corepkg-optC are modules (text files) and means nothing without corepkg.
I'm saying that because some php-* packages work standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no simple answer on your question. I find question [similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842110/dont-install-a-rpm-if-a-dependancy-installation-fails-on-pre-sections). And looks like this is only one way, you should check in `%pre` section properly installed packages, but not using `rpm` command. May be check for existing files or something like that.